# Infinite Loop Haskell

Tags: haskell, infinite-loop, ghci

```
data Node = Node Char [Node] deriving(Eq)

nodeA = Node 'A' [nodeB, nodeC, nodeD]
nodeB = Node 'B' []
nodeC = Node 'C' [nodeE, nodeF]
nodeD = Node 'D' []
nodeE = Node 'E' [nodeB]
nodeF = Node 'F' [nodeA]

deepTraverse :: Node -> [Char]
deepTraverse (Node c []) = [c]
deepTraverse (Node c ns) = c:(map (\(Node cl nsl)->cl) (buildNodeList (Node c ns) ns))
             where lssToLs lss = foldr (++) [] lss
                   buildNodeList nw nsw = lssToLs (map (\(Node cl nsl)->(if (Node cl nsl) == nw then [(Node cl nsl)]
                                                                         else ((Node cl nsl):(buildNodeList nw nsl)))) nsw)

main :: IO()
main = putStrLn (show (deepTraverse nodeA))
```

Whenever I call `deepTraverse nodeA` it loops gets hung up. In ghci it does spit out:

```
Main*> "ABCEBF
```

Leading me to suspect the "then" part of the if. I have been banging my head against this problem for a while, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tip: `lssToLs` is identical to the standard `concat` function. Also, there's a function called `concatMap`. None of which has anything to do with your bug; it's just a passing comment.

Comment: Thank you, I tested the fixed version as alluded  to in my comments on the answer given by @MathematicalOrchid with concat, and it does indeed work the same. Forgot to check the prelude functions for that one.

Comment: See also: [graph representation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732084/how-do-you-represent-a-graph-in-haskell), [detecting sharing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355772/is-it-ever-possible-to-detect-sharing-in-haskell), [equality-testing on infinite structures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28243314/is-equality-testing-possible-between-two-infinite-data-structure-in-haskell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After staring at your code for ages trying to figure out what it's supposed to do and why it's getting stuck, I think I realise the problem.

`nodeF` points back to `nodeA`. (I only just realised that!) It seems you're trying to use the `==` operator to figure out when you arrive back at a node you already looked that. That won't work.

When you say `node1 == node2`, the `==` operator will traverse *the entire tree* to see whether the two values are equal. If they *are* equal, and this structure contains an infinite loop... well, then your code loops forever! Try it. If you ask `nodeA == nodeA`, I think you'll find it *never* returns. There's your bug.

The only way to fix this is to put a genuinely *unique* label on every `Node`, and compare only the labels. You can't check whether two variables "point to" the same thing in Haskell; you can only compare whether two structures have the same value, which means traversing them completely.

Comment: I thought that it would test the data type's constructor to see if they are equal. But then I suppose that means that it will expand the node list's elements constructors. Hence the loop. I think I will test if the Char parts of node are equal. Also sorry I did say in the question that the data type represents a directed graph. And that the deep traverse is designed to move through the graph and backtrack when it reaches a dead end, stopping when it gets back to the starting node.

Comment: If the character labels are supposed to be unique then yes, this is the correct solution.

Comment: Yes, I have notice this issue. The work is for University, so I shall have to ask my lecturer if this is the case. Although, as the question states the Char value in the node declarations names I would imagine this to be the case.

Comment: @James "I thought it [`(==)`] would test the data type's constructor to see if they are equal." But your data type only has one constructor, hence any two values have the same constructor; so I don't believe that's what you thought!

Comment: @DanielWagner I meant the constructor for the constant, not the type. e.g. `Node 'A' [nodeB, nodeC, nodeD]` not `Node Char [Node]`

Comment: @James Okay, then it seems to be a terminology issue. "Constructor" specifically means only the "tag" part of the expression -- e.g. `Node` is a constructor (for things of type `Node`), `'A'` is a constructor (for things of type `Char`, `[]` and `(:)` are constructors (for things of type `[a]` for some `a`), and so on. A thing like `Node 'A' [nodeB, nodeC, nodeD]` would instead be called a "term" or an "expression"; in some cases you might also hear it called a "value". Also, you're right that it will inspect the whole value -- and that is the problem, since the value is an infinite one.