# Self-referencing data structures

Tags: haskell

I am trying to build a data structure for a graph.

The following code seems to work as intended:

```
data NodeRef = NodeRef String Int -- NodeRef name targetIndex

data Node = Node String Node -- Node name targetNode

ref0 = NodeRef "Zero" 1
ref1 = NodeRef "One" 2
ref2 = NodeRef "Two" 0
refs = [ref0, ref1, ref2]

deref :: [NodeRef] -> Node
deref refs = head allNodes
    where
        deref' (NodeRef name targetIndex) = Node name (allNodes !! targetIndex)
        allNodes = map deref' refs

showme :: Node -> Int -> [String]
showme _ 0                      = []
showme (Node name target) count = name : showme target (count - 1)

main :: IO()
main = print $ showme (deref refs) 100
```

However I have several questions:

How many "instances" of Node are created?

When I am running "showme" am I creating more nodes with each step?

What is the right way of building a data structure with circular references?

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Generally you want to represent graph edges referentially. So rather than having a vertex actually *contain* its edges, you have the vertex be a simple string or something and the edge set be `[(String, String)]` or something equally basic. [`Data.Graph`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.7/docs/Data-Graph.html) uses an adjacency list representation, defining a graph as `Array Vertex [Vertex]` (That is, an array indexed by vertices whose elements are lists of vertices)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Please take my question as an academic one. I am trying to learn the basics of haskell. And the underlying question is how can I create a collection of "objects" (not sure if this is the right name) which may contain one another.

Comment: Related reading: [How do you represent a graph in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9732084/791604), [Is equality testing possible between two infinite data structures in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28243314/791604)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How many "instances" of Node are created?

Generally when you write a data constructor such as `NodeRef` or `Node`, this represents a computation that will allocate such a value—cf. `new Node(…)` in a typical imperative/OOP language. When you write a variable binding with `let` or `where`, mentioning that name again will refer to the same value.

A top-level binding, or a `where` binding that doesn’t depend on any of the parameters, is similarly shared, and also known as a “constant applicative form” (CAF). So `ref0`, `ref1`, `ref2`, and `refs` are all CAFs and any mention of e.g. `ref0` will refer to the same `NodeRef` value.

On each invocation of `deref`, it allocates a list `allNodes` which contains as many `Node` values as there are `NodeRef` values in the input list `refs`—three in this case. The expression `allNodes !! targetIndex` refers to indices of the same shared `allNodes` list.

Finally, since `deref` returns `head allNodes`, only those nodes that are actually connected to the head node will remain reachable, and the others will be garbage-collected.

> When I am running "showme" am I creating more nodes with each step?

`showme` allocates a number of list “cons” cells `(:)` equal to the `count` argument. Or, in case `count` is negative, it will continue decrementing until wrapping around the range of `Int` and back to `0`—you can use a guard with `<=` instead, or `pred` instead of `- 1` to use a checked decrement. It does not copy the nodes themselves, only manipulating references to them (and their fields).

> What is the right way of building a data structure with circular references?

Your approach is correct here. If you want to use these circular data structures, you will need to be careful not to use naïve unbounded recursion when traversing them, so as to avoid nontermination. You also won’t be able to easily change this data structure—that is, construct an amended version of it—without losing the sharing. Therefore it’s common to just use the ID-based representation you have in `NodeRef`, which is an example of “observable sharing”, stored in a parent structure such as an `IntMap`. You might move to `Node` if you want to “freeze” the representation.

Knot-tying is more commonly used as a convenience, to avoid the need for the explicit mutation and manual sequencing used in imperative languages. As long as the dataflow isn’t circular, then you can just write the definition of a whole data structure and let the ordinary process of lazy evaluation fill it in.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed answer. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upvote. "You also won’t be able to easily change this data structure". Yes, the goal is immutability. I will accept as soon as the timer runs out.

Comment: @ChirmolStudio In the context of Haskell, people frequently say "change" to mean not "mutate", but something more like "create a new, also-immutable data structure that is very similar to an old one with some small edit applied". For example, constructing a new graph that's like the old one but with one node removed is very difficult with some graph representations.