# Is there any way to convenient way to express graphs using the tying-the-knot strategy?

Tags: haskell, graph, syntax, tying-the-knot

As explained on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159805/is-it-possible-to-do-a-search-on-a-graph-constructed-with-the-tying-the-knot-str), it is impossible to differ two graphs made using the tying the knot strategy if you don't have some kind of unique label on your nodes. Using a two-edged graph as an example:

```
data Node = Node Int Node Node

square = a where
    a = Node 0 b c
    b = Node 1 a d
    c = Node 2 a d
    d = Node 3 b c
```

Writing `square` that way is a little inconvenient and error-prone due to the need of manually writing labels. That kind of pattern would usually call for a monad:

```
square = do
    a <- Node b c
    b <- Node a d
    c <- Node a d
    d <- Node b c
    return a
```

But this also can't be  done since monads are sequential. Is there any convenient way to write tying-the-knot graphs?

Comment: GIven [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33337598/477476), maybe for your particular use case, just tying the knot might be the convenient way!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}

import Control.Monad.State

type Intividual a = State Int a

data Node = Node Int Node Node

newNode :: Node -> Node -> Intividual Node
newNode a b = state $ \i -> (Node i a b, succ i)

square :: Node
square = (`evalState`0) $ mdo
   a <- newNode b c
   b <- newNode a d
   c <- newNode a d
   d <- newNode b c
   return a
```

Comment: `RecursiveDo`, okay, I think I've heard about that someday. Thanks for your answer... can I edit a brief explanation on it?